# Which PG_CATALOG tables are effected when a Trigger is created/dropped?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a situation where a well intending person has removed a number of triggers directly from the pg_trigger table in the pg_catalog schema. This is clearly not the only table where the database stores information about the trigger as he is now getting errors. Does anyone know the list of tables that I need to modify to tidy this up?

Comment: Can you specify the error messages he is getting?

Comment: Sure thing, the error is : ERROR: 1 trigger record(s) not found for relation "tablename"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the code yet in the source tree, but here's what I can say right away.

- pg_trigger
- pg_depend
- pg_constraing (in some cases)

That's the extent I can get to right away.